# Express-Session: undefined?

Tags: node.js, session, express-session

I'm writing a chatroom for one of my school projects, however whenever I try to read my session variable I keep getting an undefined...

Essentially, my suspicions stem from the following two code blocks:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "pepperoni",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

The `"setUserInfo"`portion of this code works, and produces

> setting user information to: [object Object] 
>   user information is now: [object Object]

in the console

```
app.post("/userInfo", function(req, resp) {
    console.log(req.body);
    if(req.body.type == "setUserInfo") {
        console.log("setting user information to: " + req);
        req.session.userinformation = req;
        console.log("user information is now: " + req.session.userinformation);
    }
    if(req.body.type == "getUserInfo") {
        console.log("sending user information: " + req.session.userinformation);
        resp.send({
            status: "success",
            info: req.session.userinformation
        });
    }
})
```

When I try to use `"getUserInfo"` I get

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'userinformation' of undefined

Unfortunately, my teacher has not provided much information on sessions and many other answers here don't seem to have any effect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This `req.session.userinformation = req` does not make much sense.  You should store individual pieces of state in the session, not the entire `req` object.

Comment: Also, you probably have to save your session after modifying it.

Comment: doing both does not work... augh

Comment: If you show more of your code and your current try at it, we can probably help.